# How smart contracts are connected to my wallet?

Tags: smart-contract-wallets

I try to figure out how smart contracts that I own are connected to my wallet.
Like, what's going under the hood that allows me to see all of my assets in Metamask.

Answer (score 1):

There is no smart contract connected to a wallet.

Each token or asset operates independently from each other.

For example, you will see that this is the BUSD asset on binance smart chain:
https://bscscan.com/token/0xe9e7cea3dedca5984780bafc599bd69add087d56

If you learn a little bit of solidity, you can visit and understand its code
https://bscscan.com/address/0xe9e7cea3dedca5984780bafc599bd69add087d56#code

Since it's a BEP-20/ERC-20 token, it implements the following functions:

```
interface IBEP20 {
  /**
   * @dev Returns the amount of tokens in existence.
   */
  function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);

  /**
   * @dev Returns the token decimals.
   */
  function decimals() external view returns (uint8);

  /**
   * @dev Returns the token symbol.
   */
  function symbol() external view returns (string memory);

  /**
  * @dev Returns the token name.
  */
  function name() external view returns (string memory);

  /**
   * @dev Returns the bep token owner.
   */
  function getOwner() external view returns (address);

  /**
   * @dev Returns the amount of tokens owned by `account`.
   */
  function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);

  /**
   * @dev Moves `amount` tokens from the caller's account to `recipient`.
   *
   * Returns a boolean value indicating whether the operation succeeded.
   *
   * Emits a {Transfer} event.
   */
  function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

  /**
   * @dev Returns the remaining number of tokens that `spender` will be
   * allowed to spend on behalf of `owner` through {transferFrom}. This is
   * zero by default.
   *
   * This value changes when {approve} or {transferFrom} are called.
   */
  function allowance(address _owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);

  /**
   * @dev Sets `amount` as the allowance of `spender` over the caller's tokens.
   *
   * Returns a boolean value indicating whether the operation succeeded.
   *
   * IMPORTANT: Beware that changing an allowance with this method brings the risk
   * that someone may use both the old and the new allowance by unfortunate
   * transaction ordering. One possible solution to mitigate this race
   * condition is to first reduce the spender's allowance to 0 and set the
   * desired value afterwards:
   * https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20#issuecomment-263524729
   *
   * Emits an {Approval} event.
   */
  function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

  /**
   * @dev Moves `amount` tokens from `sender` to `recipient` using the
   * allowance mechanism. `amount` is then deducted from the caller's
   * allowance.
   *
   * Returns a boolean value indicating whether the operation succeeded.
   *
   * Emits a {Transfer} event.
   */
  function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

  /**
   * @dev Emitted when `value` tokens are moved from one account (`from`) to
   * another (`to`).
   *
   * Note that `value` may be zero.
   */
  event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

  /**
   * @dev Emitted when the allowance of a `spender` for an `owner` is set by
   * a call to {approve}. `value` is the new allowance.
   */
  event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}
```

Skipping all functions in there, we care about "balanceOf" and "transfer" functions to make you understand the idea.

BalanceOf tells you how many tokens are in a wallet (this is what your wallet software applies to tell you how many assets you have in your wallet address)

Meanwhile, transfer function allows us to transfer assets as long as the number of assets of the sender is equal or higher than the transferred amount.

**Examples**

- You have 100 BUSD in your wallet. You **won't** be able to send 101 BUSD to 0xA7434D8514004dc55c28D901F86c969e8dC97A90
- You have 100 BUSD in your wallet. You **will** be able to send 99 BUSD to 0xA7434D8514004dc55c28D901F86c969e8dC97A90

The best thing to do to see all your assets is to also visit an explorer. If you are on Ethereum, visit etherscan.io and put your address to see what assets you've got.

If your are on Binance Smart Chain, use bscscan.com

**Transfers, more advanced**
We also have transferFrom function, approve and allowance.

Let's say I want to let your address spend 100 of BUSD of my address without sending the BUSD directly to you. I can call the "approve" function on your address with the capital I want to approve

Example: approve(your_address, _amount)

The function "allowance" allows us to see how much approval an asset owner gave to another address. If I call after approving your address the function
allowance(my_address, your_address) the amount out will be _amount which was passed in approve.

The function transferFrom works as long as the following parameters are met:

1. the msg.sender has approval of the amount that is being transferred, which approval should be equal to the same value or higher
2. the wallet from which funds are sent has enough funds to send (balanceOf)

Example, after approving your address for 100 BUSD:

- You **can** transferFrom(_myAddress, any_address, 100 BUSD) as long as you have approval and there are 100 BUSD in _myAddress
- You **cannot** transferFrom(_myAddress, any_address, 100 BUSD) if there are not at least 100 BUSD in _myAddress
- You **can** transferFrom(_myAddress, any_address, 50 BUSD) and call again transferFrom(_myAddress, any_address, 50 BUSD) as long as you have approval for 100 BUSD and there are 100 BUSD in _myAddress
- You **cannot** transferFrom(_myAddress, any_address, 100 BUSD) if approval was not given to you

Overall your funds are protected by well thought programmed blockchain logic. As long as you stick to standard products for the beggining (e.g USDT assets, DAI, WETH, WBNB, etc.) you shouldn't have any problems understanding this better.

Comment: thanks a lot!
you really helped me understand the whole concept and what's going on.